# Loading File Names into a TStrings

Tags: delphi

hello i am trying to load a list of filenames from a folder into a Stringlist. I only want to add the names of files that end in .jpg  When i run it now i get access violation errors. Here is what i got.

Selects directory.

```
procedure TMainForm.Load1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DirName: string;
begin
    mylist.Free;
    myList := TList<TBitmap>.Create;
  DirName := 'c:\';
  if SelectDirectory(DirName,[sdAllowCreate, sdPerformCreate, sdPrompt],SELDIRHELP)
  then;
    LoadImages(DirName);
end;
```

Gets number of totalfiles in folder

```
function GetFilesCount(Dir : string; Mask : string) : integer;
var
  Path : string;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for Path in TDirectory.GetFiles(Dir, Mask) do
    inc(Result);
end;
```

Gets filenames from folder

```
function TMainForm.GetFilenames(Path: string ):TStrings;
var
  Dest: TStrings;
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  Dest.create;
  if FindFirst(Path+'*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  repeat
    Dest.Add(SR.Name);
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  FindClose(SR);
  Result := Dest;
  Dest.Free;
end;
```

and the load iamges

```
    procedure TMainForm.LoadImages(const Dir: string);
    const
      FIRST_IMAGE = 0;
    var
      iFile : Integer;
      CurFileName: string;
      FoundFile : boolean;
      FileNameTemplate : string;
      FileNames : Tstrings;
    begin
       FileNames.Create;
       FileNameTemplate := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Dir) + '*.jpg';          FileNames:=GetFileNames(FileNameTemplate);                                                 
      try
        ifile := 0;                                                                 
        repeat
          CurFileName := FileNames.Names[ifile];                                      
          showmessage(Curfilename);
 if FoundFile then
      begin
        end;
        Inc(iFile);
      end;
    until not FoundFile;
end;
```

Comment: Where do you get the access violation? It's much easier if we don't have to guess.

Comment: Result := Dest; Dest.Free; Oops, you just destroyed your result.

Comment: @Glen Many apologies for my earlier comment here, just a personal overreaction. I've been finding myself more and more critical lately and have become ruthless along with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here (where you actually have two problems) - actually, you have the same problems twice in your code:

```
Dest.Create;  // In GetFileNames

FileNames.Create; // In LoadImages
```

First, `TStrings` is an abstract class. You can't create an instance of it; it's the basis for other more concrete classes like `TStringList`. Create one of those concrete classes instead.

Second, you have to create the `TStringList` and store a reference to it.

```
FileNames := TStringList.Create;
```

The better way to do it is to create your stringlist and pass it into the function or procedure, since you need the results when it returns. I'll take a quick pass at one of them for you:

```
function TMainForm.GetFilenames(const Path: string; const FileList: TStringList ): Boolean;
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(FileList));      // Make sure it was created and passed in
  FileList.Clear;                  // Remove any previous names
  if FindFirst(Path+'*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  repeat
    FileList.Add(SR.Name);
  until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
  FindClose(SR);
  Result := FileList.Count > 0;  // Return true if we have found any files
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
FileNames := TStringList.Create;
try
  if GetFileNames(PathToFolder, FileNames) then
  begin
    // Process files here
    for i := 0 to FileNames.Count - 1 do
    begin
      CurrFile := FileNames[i];
      // Use the file here from CurrFile
    end;

  end;
finally
  FileNames.Free;
end;
```

Comment: updated code like you said (see above) but now i gett access violation error on teh load images "CurFileName := FileNames.Names[ifile];  '

Comment: Glen, you're not populating the stringlist before accessing things in it in your loop. You have to *put stuff in it before you can use it*. Also, please don't use StackOverflow to SO is not a place to [evolve your project](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133222/172661). Posting a question, receiving an answer, and then editing your question to change it to ask another question is not how this site works. One question, one post, and don't change the question after it's been answered. :-) It's hard to hit a moving target.

Comment: Sorry i was accesssing it but forgot to add that line when i was posting i guess.. I have FileNames := GetFileNames(FileNameTemplate); under FileNameTemplate :=  and before the try.  Also some people tell me to edit my main post ,  others say not to?  but either way iam still getting access errors..

Comment: @glen The problem with your edit is that you make this answer look stupid. It was a good answer to your original question.

Comment: You're freeing the list before the function returns. Once you assign it to `Result`, freeing it with `Dest.Free` also frees it in `Result`. My suggestion would be to change your function to accept a stringlist as a parameter, and populate that stringlist in the function. Editing your main post is fine, if you're adding more details. It's not when you're changing the entire meaning of the question or asking a different question entirely.

Comment: ahh ok i see, i will change it back :D  So other users will know what you were talking about if they look. Thanks.

Comment: Try my last edit, which rewrites `GetFilenames` to demonstrate a possibly better way to do what you want to do. And yes, you got it; that's exactly why not to change the question after you get answers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetAllFiles(AFolder: string; AMask: string; AStringList: TStringList): integer;
// Add all files matching AMask in AFolder to AStringList. Returns number of files
var
  iSearch: TSearchRec;
  iCount: integer;
  iFileAttrs: integer;
begin
  iCount := 0;
  iFileAttrs := $23 - faHidden;
  // Find all files
  if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(AFolder) + AMask, iFileAttrs, iSearch) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      // Add the files to the stringlist
      AStringList.Add(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(AFolder) + iSearch.name);
      inc(iCount);
    until FindNext(iSearch) <> 0;
  end;
  FindClose(iSearch);
  Result := iCount;
end;
```

Comment: -1 Spewing some code into an answer, without explanation, is poor form. Spend the time to explain yourself.

Comment: David, I think your comment and downvote are unnecessarily harsh.  I don't expect you to agree with me, but I hope you'll consider.  This was a well-meaning answer, the code has relevant comments, and the tone of your comment could have been just as valid if it had been less harsh.  User might've then been motivated to improve their answer.  You have 200x the rep of the person you're stomping on - poor form.

Comment: Some sub-communities (like the Python people here) prefer the code sample over the long winded english.  They have a point.

Comment: @Argalatyr I don't agree with you. This is in my view very poor quality. The code isn't great: what's $23? But it mostly bears no relation to the question. How does it fix the AV? Bill has 482 rep and should know better by now. I don't agree with Warren on this one. Code without explanation is almost always poor.